# Understanding Atmel 9x60EK Shutdown Circuitry

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design

I'm trying to understand the shutdown circuitry behind the Atmel 9x60 Evaluation Kit:

[image]

So for normal operation, `J3` is `OPEN`.

The processor drives `SHDN` high (which I assume means "run"), the following happens:

- `Q3` conducts, causing the `STARTB` line to go to `LOW`.
- `Q4` loses the gate voltage, causing `POWER_EN` to go `HIGH`.
- `Q5` also loses gate voltage, causing `MIC2800_nRST` to go `HIGH`.

But when `J3` is `CLOSED`, `POWER_EN` will remain `HIGH` as well as `MIC2800_nRST`, regardless of how `SHDN` is driven. (Obviously this would mean that the MIC2800 remains in power-enabled and keeps the power rails active).

The confusing part for me is that `MIC2800_nRST` is shown as an output from the MIC2800-G8YSML:

[image]

Does this mean that the shutdown circuit **and** the MIC2800 both drive the `MIC2800_nRST` line? In this case, why is Q5 there? POR in the MIC2800 is an open-drain output. Assuming that J3 would always be `OPEN`, it doesn't seem to serve any purpose since driving `POWER_EN` low will remove power from the rails and turn the processor off anyway. It looks like it just makes sure it is either a weak pull-up or a strong pull-down.

[Datasheet for the MIC2800](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC2800%20-%20Digital%20Power%20Management%20IC%202%20DS20005839B.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

> By setting jumper J2/J3 the user can shut down the MPU without powering down its power rails

This is precisely the use case it's there for - you can put the processor in a low power shutdown state without powering down anything else that might need those supplies.

The `POR` pin on the MIC2800 is an open drain output and requires a pull up or pull down. When `!SHDN`, it will be pulled high through `R17`. Per the datasheet, `POR` will go low if either/both of the outputs goes out of regulation. Therefore, you can monitor the `MIC2800_nRST` signal to check the regulator output is healthy. When `SHDN` is set, obviously the supply will be out of regulation (as it's off), so it gets pulled low by `Q5`.